# Can I use Canada "permanent" postage stamps, usually for lettermail, towards higher postage rates?

Tags: canada

For a couple of years, Canada's had "permanent" postage stamps, whereby instead of printing a fixed value in cents on the regular lettermail stamp there is simply the letter "**P**" for *permanent*.

You used to buy 1 or 2 cent stamps to make up for any year's price increase if you had stamps left over from the previous year.  Unlike those old stamps, "**P**" stamps are good from one year to the next *despite* price increases.  i.e. they are guaranteed to maintain their "purchasing power" to mail a *regular letter* within Canada.

My question is:  Can the Canada "**P**" stamps be used as part postage when sending other kinds of mail, e.g. internationally, or oversize?  Each of those is a higher postage rate than the "**P**" stamp's value.

That is, can the "**P**" stamps have a specific value when used in combination with other stamps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this on the [Canada Post](http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/personal/productsservices/atoz/permanentstamp.jsf) website

> The PERMANENT™ stamp, identified with the letter P in place of a value, is always accepted at the current domestic postage price.
>
> Self-adhesive PERMANENT stamps are available in booklets as well as in coils of 100 stamps. One stamp can be used to mail a letter anywhere in Canada that weighs up to 30 grams or more postage can be added to mail larger letters, parcels or to send mail internationally.

I will assume that means that when the "P" stamp is used as part of postage it takes on the value of the current domestic postage price.